# Compute the fundamental group and the first homology group of two discs attatched to $S^1$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be the space obtained by attaching two discs to the circle $S^1$. The first disc is attached by its boundary via the map $z \mapsto z^3$ and the second disc is attached by its boundary via the map $z\mapsto z^5$. How do I compute the fundamental group and the first homology group.

I understand that I need to use the Seifert-van Kapen theorem.

Comment: Do you know about CW complex structure? The fundamental group has generators given by the one cells and the relations are given by the attaching map of two cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the discs $U_1,U_2.$ we want to know the fundamental group of $X=U_1\cup U_2.$ and will use Seifert-van Kampen. From Wikipedia:
[image: pushout diagram]

Let $\pi_1(U_1\cap U_2)=\langle a\rangle, \pi_1(U_1)=1, \pi_1(U_2)=1.$
Then we get $i_1 : a\mapsto 1,$ and $i_2 : a\mapsto 1.$ and we can write down:

$$\pi_1 X = 1 \ast_{\Bbb Z} 1 = \langle a | a =1, a = 1\rangle = 1.$$

But then we probably could have guessed that answer without working it out.

Answer (score 1):

Take the first attaching map $D^2 \to S^1$ by $z \mapsto z^3$.
It's clear that a loop in $S^1$ becomes trivial after wrapping it around three times, so the fundamental group here is 
$$\langle a \mid a^3=1 \rangle=\mathbf Z_3$$
where $\langle a \rangle=\pi_1(S^1).$

Likewise the second relation gives that
$\langle a \mid a^5=1\rangle$
and together, these relations imply that $a^3=a^5=1$ or $1=a^2=a^{3}$ and so $a=1$ follows meaning that the group is trivial.

---

A way  the first argument precise is that the universal cover of the first map attached by $z \mapsto z^3$ is three disks attached by identity to their boundary, where deck transformations are cyclic permutations of these disks, 
which gives you the desired fundamental group.